# Keras Word2Vec implementation

Tags: python, keras, word2vec

I'm using the implementation found in http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/ to learn something about word2Vec. What I am not understanding is why isn't the loss function decreasing?

```
Iteration 119200, loss=0.7305528521537781
Iteration 119300, loss=0.6254740953445435
Iteration 119400, loss=0.8255964517593384
Iteration 119500, loss=0.7267132997512817
Iteration 119600, loss=0.7213149666786194
Iteration 119700, loss=0.6156617999076843
Iteration 119800, loss=0.11473365128040314
Iteration 119900, loss=0.6617216467857361
```

The net, from my understanding, is a standard one used in this task:

```
input_target = Input((1,))
input_context = Input((1,))

embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, vector_dim, input_length=1, name='embedding')

target = embedding(input_target)
target = Reshape((vector_dim, 1))(target)
context = embedding(input_context)
context = Reshape((vector_dim, 1))(context)

dot_product = Dot(axes=1)([target, context])
dot_product = Reshape((1,))(dot_product)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dot_product)

model = Model(inputs=[input_target, input_context], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop') #adam??
```

Words come from a vocabulary of size 10000 from http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip (english text)

What I notice is that some words are somewhat learned in time like the context for numbers and articles is easily guessed, yet the loss is quite stuck around 0.7 from the beginning, and as iterations goes it only fluctuates randomly.

The training part is made like this (which I sense strange since the absence of the standard fit method)

```
arr_1 = np.zeros((1,))
arr_2 = np.zeros((1,))
arr_3 = np.zeros((1,))
for cnt in range(epochs):
    idx = np.random.randint(0, len(labels)-1)
    arr_1[0,] = word_target[idx]
    arr_2[0,] = word_context[idx]
    arr_3[0,] = labels[idx]
    loss = model.train_on_batch([arr_1, arr_2], arr_3)
    if cnt % 100 == 0:
        print("Iteration {}, loss={}".format(cnt, loss))
```

Am i missing something important about these type of net? What is not written is implemented exactly like the link above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed the same tutorial and the loss drops after the algorithm went through a sample again. Note that the loss function is calculated only for the current target and context word pair. In the code example from the tutorial one epoch is only one sample, therefore you would need more than the number of target and context words to come to a point where the loss drops.

I implemented the training part with the following line

```
model.fit([word_target, word_context], labels, epochs=5)
```

Be warned that this can take a long time depending on how large the corpus is. The [`train_on_batch`](https://keras.io/models/model/#train_on_batch) function gives you more control in training and you can vary the batch size or select samples you choose at every step of the training.